# failed to download dav1d

Tags: opencv, installation

When I was trying to install opencv on mac using "brew install opencv@3", I got stuck on downloading dav1d and got the error message:

==> Fetching dav1d

==> Downloading https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d-test-data/raw/1.1.0/8-b

curl: (7) Failed to connect to code.videolan.org port 443: Operation timed out

Error: dav1d: Failed to download resource "dav1d--00000000.ivf"

Download failed: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d-test-data/raw/1.1.0/8-bit/data/00000000.ivf

I searched dav1d and tried to see what happened to https://code.videolan.org/videolan/ but failed to load it too.

Comment: I have a similar problem while installing 'libdav1d' on a docker image. `Failed to connect to code.videolan.org port 443: Connection refused`. I tried several DNS providers, reboots, prune, but nothing seems to help

Comment: @iSenne have you been able to resolve this? I have the same issue with docker as well

Comment: code.videolan.org is currently down (with more VideoLAN servers). Relevant [tweet](https://twitter.com/videolan/status/1629070733484691456?s=20) There's mirrors of those repositories at [github](https://github.com/orgs/videolan/repositories) in case you can find what you need there

Comment: I saw the tweet. How unlucky am I :(